# pgsql2shp issue when using WITH clause

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, pgsql2shp

I'm using `pgsql2shp.exe` from a Windows batch file and I get an error when using a `WITH` clause:

```
    "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pgsql2shp.exe" [ ... ] "WITH test AS (SELECT gid, the_geom FROM siveer_aep.geo_c_3_0_3) SELECT * FROM test"
```

The `[ ... ]` stands for options I consider pointless here.

I have tried a simple query that runs fine. The error output is:

```
Table geo_c_3_0_3) SELECT * FROM test does not exist
```

It looks like `WITH` clause syntax is misinterpreted by the exec...

I have not found anything on the Internet about this issue. Any idea?

Comment: sql looks fine. Have you tried double quotes around the schema and/or table name e.g."siveer_aep"."geo_c_3_0_3"? You will probably need to escape these quotes as they're already inside double quotes. Not sure how you do that on windows but I'd try \" first.

Comment: I get the following error: `Table "geo_c_3_0_3") SELECT * FROM aep does not exist`...

Comment: I see the same thing. You might want to try **ogr2ogr** instead, although I can't seem to get it to work at the moment. It might also be a problem with 'laundering' field names (keeping them 10 characters or less), I think ogr2ogr does this but i'm not sure about pgsql2shp